# should we ask question and answer them implementing always an images, if it is possible?

Tags: discussion, support

I think that this group should, more than other groups, play on the implementation of images in questions and answers. We are working with visual, and we need a more visual approach. Shouldn't insert in the FAQ a note to say something about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's naturally tending towards that, but there are plenty of questions where an image really doesn't matter. Also, keep it mind that complete newbies can't post images, I think the minimum reputation to post an image is around 16. That'll make it harder to get new people into our community...

Comment: I didn't know about the image upload was limited :(

Answer (score 1):

I would tend not to actively *encourage* it. Having the upload button present should be sufficient. I think when a question can profit from an image, users will discover the feature on their own; and there's  always the possibility to ask for an image in the comments.